# unable to launch application when lync is running?

Tags: windows, delphi, lync, delphi-5

I am working on some strange issue with my `delphi` application.
The scenario is as follows:

If `microsoft Lync` is running on my machine and if I want to launch my application, it does not getting displayed but the process was started for my application.

and when I close the `lync`, immediately my application gets visible.
Below are some points which you may need:

1. My application does not have any link with `Microsoft Lync`.
2. `Application` process is running when I close the `lync`
3. `Form.Show()` is the last statement called from my code.
4. This issue is not replicated on every machine.

I am not sure why this is happening.

Can anyone help me on this?

Any help or suggestion will be useful for me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's special about your program? Does the same happen with a vanilla VCL forms app?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan my program is just a simple program does not have any thing special. just a main form and a child form which is called by using ShowModal().
No it is not happening with every app, only with the my app

Comment: Does the same happen with a vanilla VCL forms app?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get the meaning of `vanilla VCL forms app`?

Comment: Create a brand new VCL forms app and test it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Ok will check thanks.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan yes this is happinning with VCl form app too.

Comment: That's pretty weird. I think I'd use some trace debugging to investigate further. Probably going to need to instrument the VCL code.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I have some Spy++ trace for the same but it is not that much clear. I can provide the same will it be helpful?. about the VCL froms it does not seen anything which and make the application wait till now.

Comment: Spy++ message trace will be overwhelming. Needs serious filtering. I think this is one for you to debug.

Comment: What are the names of your problem app and the new VCL one?  Do you get the same results if you move them to a different folder?

Comment: I have the same problem but with Lync. When I try so start Lync it says that another window of Microsoft Outlook is already created and it abort Lync.

Answer (score 0):

Finally,
After a long checking of the code I came to know that this problem is due to the setting desktop as a parent window somewhere in the code.
Refer this link for [SetParent()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633541(v=vs.85).aspx).

When this problem has been discussed with the microsoft I came to know that the Lync is having some issue with some application when we call `SetParent(Handle, 0)` this will go for a long wait state.

**Solution:**
What I did is as the `SetParent`function call was important in my code I assign the `SetParent` property of the form to my application handle so this solves my problem.

The above step is done because in spy++ I found that every delphi application as 2 instances 1 is for `TApplication` and another is for `MainFrom i.e. TForm` of the same application.